# Nil value error in LuaTeX when \bullet is replaced with text

Tags: errors, luatex, sseq

I'm trying to draw a spectral sequence using `luasseq`, and getting the following error message:

```
LuaTeX error /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/scripts/luasseq/luasseq.lua:377: attempt 
to index field 'wd' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/scripts/luasseq/luasseq.lua:377: in function 'sse
q_register_size'
[string "\directlua "]:1: in main chunk.
l.2 \directlua0{sseq_register_size()}

l.16 \ssdrop[color=green]{3}
```

Here is a (not)working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{luatextra}
\usepackage{luasseq}

\begin{document}

\begin{sseq}[grid=chess]{0...3}{0...2}
\ssdrop[color=green]{3}
\ssmove{0}{1}
\ssdrop[color=red]{\bullet}
\ssarrow{2}{-1}
\ssdrop[color=red]{\bullet}
\end{sseq}

\end{document}
```

It works fine without the line `\ssdrop[color=green]{3}`. Any ideas why this line is causing a nil value error?

Comment: The luasseq seems rather old. I think `gfind` should be changed
into `gmatch` in luasseq.lua for the latest luaTeX.
With this change, I obtained the same error for
`\ssdrop[color=green]{3}`.
It worked without the line as in the case of Adina.

Comment: I found an answer by Taco about `tex.wd` etc. Thanks.

Comment: @AkiraKakuto Oh right, I did modify luasseq.lua by changing gfind into gmatch -- forgot to mention that! And I also applied the change Taco mentioned in http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24103/6894. Still can't get that line to work though.

Comment: Here your example with the line
`\ssdrop[color=green]{3}`
works without any error message.
`This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.80.0`, (prerelease one).

Comment: This works in TeX Live 2015

Comment: What version of TeX are you using i.e. TeX Live or MikTeX and which version?

Comment: @cfr I'm currently using TeX Live 2015. Though I just tried my MWE again, and today the error I'm getting is ``LaTeX Error: File `luatextra.sty' not found.'' So now to figure out where that went...

Comment: luatexextra.sty is in texlive but it is just half a dozen packages loading packages you probably don't need, just use `\usepackage{fontspec}`

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle. So I just tried it with `\usepackage{fontspec}` and without `\usepackage{luatextra}`, and now the error I'm getting is `LaTeX Error: File \`luaotfload.sty' not found`.

Comment: @AdinaG luatex isn't going to work at all really without luaotfload.sty that is the main font loader than allows it to use system unicode fonts. You only have a partial tex installation you should update.