# Example of luasseq

Tags: sseq

Does anybody have an example of a LaTeX code using `luasseq`?

I tried to use it but it doesn't work (at least for me). Do I have to install something besides the package?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please show us a simple code, complete, to check it?

Comment: Just to confirm, you're using LuaLaTeX rather than just LaTeX, correct?

Comment: Related? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233885/nil-value-error-in-luatex-when-bullet-is-replaced-with-text Is your TeX distribution up to date? Which are you using?